# Upgrading Azure SQL Server pricing tier while being under failover group

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have 2 Azure SQL databases both are backing each other up in a failover group. However, each of them is in a different pricing tier (one in a basic and the other one in a standard).

I want them both in the same pricing tier (standard) but when trying to upgrade the basic one the standard option is grayed out and says:

> This edition is not available since the geo-replicated database has a lower edition

.

is there any workaround to matching both database specs?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do scaling operations in database that are geo-replicated is the following:

Scale UP: First scale up all the secondaries and after that scale up the primary.

Scale Down: First scale down the primary and then scale down the secondaries.

Scale down the primary, then scale up the secondary, after that scale up the primary again.